# Can someone explain me how to use paraments correctly in this example?

Tags: javascript

I'm trying JS. I have used only Python recently. 
And there is a problem, look at this example:

```
var myCharacter = {
  name: "character",
  avatarImage: "avatar.png",
  experience: 1,
  level: 1,
  items: {helmetSlot: blank, armorSlot: blank}, //'items' will be changed into 'inventory'
  backpack: [],
  strength: 0,
  //It is corrent 'method'?
  takeOff: function(slot) {
      if (this.backpack.length < 10) { //setting backpack length
          this.backpack.push(this.items.slot)
          this.items.slot = blank
      }
     else {}
  }

}

myCharacter.takeOff(helmetSlot) //why it doesn't work? I know it did't declared but ... You know I want to use 'word' helmetSlot to make block 'takeOff' way I want, I have used to do things like this in python
```

Problem is in method `takeOff`. Can you explain me how to use it like I can do it in Python?

Here is full code:  https://pastebin.com/NP1KLPie

I know I have done it wrong, but how to use it the way I want?

Comment: you can pass a string into takeOff like this myCharacter.takeOff('helmetSlot'), then in takeOff change 'this.items.slot' to 'this.items[slot]' it should work. Also you didnt declare blank anywhere in your code.

Comment: How would you do it in Python?

Comment: It's declared: var blank = new Item("nothing", nothing, "blank.png", 0, 0, 0). Anyway thanks I'll try it.

Answer (score 0):

`this.items.slot` is looking for a property literally named "slot".  Instead you can use square brackets to use a variable property name: `this.items[slot]` (passing a  string value into `slot`.)

```js
var myCharacter = {
  name: "character",
  avatarImage: "avatar.png",
  experience: 1,
  level: 1,
  items: { helmetSlot: "helmet", armorSlot: "armor" }, // using strings instead of the `blank` variable, just so the results will be visible
  backpack: [],
  strength: 0,
  takeOff: function(slot) {
    if (this.backpack.length < 10) {
      this.backpack.push(this.items[slot]) // not this.items.slot
      this.items[slot] = "empty" // string instead of `blank` again
    } else {}
  }
}

myCharacter.takeOff("helmetSlot") // pass a string, not a bare variable name
console.log(myCharacter) // check the results
```

Answer (score -1):

in your code values you are using for helmetSlot and armorSlot is not valid .Because in javascript you can can assign one of the below values to variablesor properties of objects

```
a) String  ('' or 'somevalue') 
b Number
c) undefined
d) null
e) {}  
f) function (){
....
} 





 var myCharacter = {
      name: "character",
      avatarImage: "avatar.png",
      experience: 1,
      level: 1,
      items: {helmetSlot:'', armorSlot: ''}, //'items' will be changed into 'inventory'
      backpack: [],
      strength: 0,
      //It is corrent 'method'?
      takeOff: function(slot) {
          if (this.backpack.length < 10) { //setting backpack length
              this.backpack.push(this.items.slot)
              this.items.slot = undefined;
          }
         else {}
      }

    };
    console.log(myCharacter);


    myCharacter.takeOff(10);
```